# Logo redesign suggestions

Tags: logo, branding, fine-arts, concept-art

I have a client who wants to redo his website logo redone.

He don't want to use or incorporate cliches like such as the magnifying glass and buildings. He wants a "pear" to be his logo/branding to represent his business. It is the same concept as Apple, as apple is and IT company but it uses an Apple to as a logo. As of now he is using a real pear image, I was thinking it can be modified into a fine-art like "Apple" company but with original and creative style.

I want your advise that how should I modify this logo, as well as which fonts would suit with the new logo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to steer away from cliches? I think a magnifying glass in the shape of a pear would be great. Easy, clean, recognisable. Isn't that what a logo should be? Anyway, not much of an answer but I would go more to the iconic logo side than an image like this.

Comment: I am absolutely agree with you Jane, and I made couple of logo based on this concept and tried to understand my client, but he don't want to understand it.

Comment: This is much too broad of a question.  You should come back to us with some examples of what you're working on, following [these guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682) and then maybe we can help you more.

Comment: Please do not request for your question to be removed after someone has taken the time out to answer it just because you no longer want your question visible.  If there are some discrepancies then please make an [edit] so you can receive a better answer.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is a request for free work.

Answer (score 2):

It's funny that i found the "same" logo on google images with the search "pear from letters logo"....

[image]

**In my opinion**, a logo that is made from the words that your client want in a shape of a pear will be an interesting approach on that.

[image]

Of course, it should not look playful as this example. It needs to be more serious.

Comment: Yes I found the exactly the same logo in google image search.

I like the idea but the question is, how to make it look serious?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do not use real imagery. What dimshik found is cool, but because it seems like a pretty serious company I would explore having a pear as an icon and the wordmark separate.
In terms of fonts, if you still plan on manipulating the wordmark into a pear shape, I would try a tall sans serif like Oswald or something to downplay the cutesiness of a pear wordmark.